# Localizing strings in WPF codebehind using XAML ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, resourcedictionary

I'm localizing a WPF app using the LocBaml method. Everything works great for UI defined in .xaml files. However I have a few strings that are generated in codebehind that must also be localized. So I tried to take the approach recommended by Microsoft in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547.aspx) article. I have a xaml resource dictionary file as such:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

     <!-- String resource that can be localized -->
     <system:String x:Uid="system:String_1" x:Key="localizedMessage">en-US Message</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I then use a third-party tool to generate the localized resources.dll containing a spanish version of the resource dictionary.

However, when I call

```
string localizedMessage = (string)Application.Current.Resources["localizedMessage"];
```

localizedMessage always returns the value defined in the en-US version of the dll. I must be misunderstanding something. What do I have to do to get the localized version of the string returned?

Comment: Did you define assembly culture? (It should stay neutral.) Is your thread's culture en-US or the expected localized one (should be the latter)? What happens if you refer to the resource from some XAML? (`<Label Text="{DynamicResource localizedMessage}"/>`)

Comment: By the way, the parameters `x:Uid="system:String_1" x:Key="localizedMessage"` should be the same, AFAIK. (That is, `x:Uid="localizedMessage" x:Key="localizedMessage"`.)

Comment: In my AssemblyInfo.cs I have `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]`, and setting a breakpoint at the call to pull the Resources reveals my thread culture and uiculture are both set to "es"

Comment: and what does `string localizedMessage = (string)FindResource("localizedMessage");` return?

Comment: @Vlad FindResource() also returns the en-US version of the string

Comment: Okay, and what if you refer to the resource from XAML?

Comment: referring to the resource from XAML also shows the en-US version. However I do see localized text on a button in the same .xaml file.

Comment: okay, so we are closer :) could you please see in the Modules window in Visual Studio (you are using MSVC, right?), if the dll with localized strings is loaded at all? I bet it isn't.

Comment: Both versions of the .resources.dll are loaded

Comment: Hm, that's really strange. Could you please try to replace `x:Uid`'s value with `"localizedMessage"`?

Comment: making the x:Uid and x:Key values the same had no affect.

Comment: Let's check more things then. (1) The resource dictionary is the sole content of the `.resources.dll`, right? (2) The resource dictionary with the same name exists in the main application, and contains the same data (except that the strings differ) (3) The resource dictionary is included as MergedDictionary into `Application.Resources`. (4) The program's language is not changed during runtime. Right?

Comment: (1) The .resources.dll contains 2 .baml files, MainWindow.baml and StringResources.baml. MainWindow.baml has localized content which is loading correctly. (2) yes (3) yes (4) Currently i'm setting the thread's culture and UIculture to "es" in App.xaml.cs in the OnStartup method. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: (1) Well, I would better leave only one baml there, perhaps split the dll into 2 ones. (4) The dictionary is loaded only once, so OnStartup could be way too late. I would try to move the language setting to App's constructor's beginning.

Comment: (4) Another idea could be reloading the resource dictionary every time the language is changing (I used this approach for dynamic localization in my last project).

Comment: That was it. I was just setting the culture too late, after the Resources were already loaded. Moving this logic to the App constructor did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay :) So we have the answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with the OP, the problem is in setting the language too late (in `App`'s `OnStartup`).

Indeed, the localized resource dictionaries are loaded once, using the current language of the thread. If the thread language changes too late, the resources are already loaded, and no reload is triggered.

A solution in this particular case would be to change the UI thread's locale as early as possible -- that is, in the `App`'s constructor.

Comment: I found out that I had to set the thread's locale even before calling InitializeComponent() in the App's constructor. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @TomasKohl: Indeed! `InitializeComponent` loads and interprets XAML, so this might already load the resource dictionaries.